# Динамическая компиляция и IWshRuntimeLibrary C#

Tags: c#, windows, компиляция

Необходимо динамически скомпилировать код на c#, внутри которого можно будет сделать "using IWshRuntimeLibrary;"

```
    CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters { OutputAssembly = "output.exe", GenerateExecutable = true };

     //Та чудо-строчка, которая по идее должна работать, но нет.                 
       compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll");  

        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(
                    new Dictionary<String, String> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });

        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, this.source_code);'
```

this.source_code - код, который мы компилируем ( и в котором нужно использовать using IWshRuntimeLibrary; )

Comment: А что в точности значит «по идее должна работать, но нет»? И какое вы получаете сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: Number of Errors: 1
ERROR Не удалось найти файл метаданных "Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll"

Comment: Ну так сделайте так, чтобы нашло. Укажите полный путь, что ли?